# PHP: includes and folders

Tags: php, include, directory

I have a small PHP website with most of my pages of the form:

```
<?php include("heading.php"); ?>

<!-- Content of the page -->

<?php include("footing.php"); ?>
```

Where "footing" contains some stuff to put at the end of each file and "heading" a lot of stuff (including another include for the menu). The problem is: I'm starting to have a lot of php file sand I would like to put some of them in folders. The straightforward way to do it is to change the code for the files in the folder to:

```
<?php include("../heading.php"); ?>

<!-- Content of the page -->

<?php include("../footing.php"); ?>
```

But it doesn't work as the include literately copy the code instead of executing it in the original file's folder, so any include and css in heading.php won't be found unless I copy those files in the new folder.

Comment: strightforward is to use absolute path

Comment: Right (sorry, didn't see k102's comment before submitting my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify heading.php so that the paths to the files it loads are absolute. For example, if you load a CSS file from `css/style.css` use `/css/style.css` or `http://example.com/css/style.css` instead.

Comment: Or have some sort of config variable or function that lets you say `<link href="<?php echo $config->base_url; ?>/css/style.css">`.

Comment: and it's much better to have one include file with defined path to css, php and other files so to change it faster

Answer (score 2):

You also can edit the include path, either in php.ini or directly in your code:

```
//Must be called before every include, if not stated in your php.ini
$PATH=get_include_path();
set_include_path($PATH.":/absolute/path/to/your/include/folder/");
```

Then you can use your include this way, even if you are in a sub directory:

```
<?php
  include "heading.php"; //no brackets
  include "whatever.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are just losing track of where you are in your directory structure. Using **../** takes you back one level and using **./** (or just **/**) takes you back to the root directory and **../../** takes you back two levels.

The trick is to know where you are in the directory structure and where the file is that you want to include. If you are including or linking to a file in your **css** folder but you are in a file that is located in the **inc** folder you have to go back to the root and then to **css** so you would put **/css/filename.ext**

However, if you are in the **fonts/glyphicons** folder and want to link to a font in the **fonts/font-awesome** folder you could just use **../font-awesome**. Clear as mud?

What I do is create three (or more) folders. This helps keep the various files organized and with abbreviated lettering, namely:

- css   (for stylesheets like bootstrap.css, style.css, etc.)
- img   (for images, graphics, icons, etc.)
- font  (for fonts, glyphicons, font-awesome, etc.)
- inc   (for includes/'snippets' like your heading.php and footing.php)
- js    (for javascripts such as html5shiv.js, boostrap.js, etc.)

Then in my heading.html file (I use html for the header and footer) I include some items like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
        <meta name="Description" content="<?php echo $page_description; ?>">
        <meta name="Keywords" content="<?php echo $page_keywords; ?>">
        <meta name="Author" content="<?php echo $author_name; ?>">
        <meta name="Viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link href="/css/quicksite-redsand.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/img/mm.png" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
```

Then in my pages such as the index.php (homepage) I set up some parameters for that particular page plus include some snippets such as header, menu(s), other body text items, and footer, like so:

```
    <?php 
    $page_name = 'Homepage';
    $page_author = 'My Name...';
    $page_keywords = 'home, home page, homepage';
    $page_description = 'This is the home page for the ...';
    $active_home = 'class="active"';
    $select_home = 'class="selected"';
    include ('inc/config.php');  //common to all pages
    include ('inc/header.html'); //common to all pages
    include ('inc/menus.html');  //common to all pages
    include ('inc/banner.html');
    include ('inc/review.html');
    include ('inc/footer.html'); //common to all pages
    ?>
```

Since in your index.php and probably most of your pages you are at root level, in the home directory so to speak, you only need **inc** without the **/**. Looks like PHP doesn't like unnecessary /'s as it gave me an error when I tried...

I know this is a long winded answer but thought I would illustrate for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok not strictly an answer to your question, but try doing it the other way, have a layout file which has the header and footer included and include the main bit of content dynamically.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        etc...

        <?php include_once '/path/to/content.php'; ?>

        etc...

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem properly , but I have the following answer 
I think you should use relative css paths to your website address 
for example if we have a css file it should be like that

```
<link ...src="/styles/somecss.css">
```

so where ever you put it in your application this would take the path
http://wesiteaddres/style/somecss.css

and you can set your include path to whatever directory you want
set_include_path() ;

Hope this would help